# transiting through Narita airport with less than 6 month passport validity

Tags: transit-visas, japan, nrt, japanese-visitors

I will be transiting through NRT on DEL-NRT-SFO route.

The onwrd flight is on the same calender day after 4 hr. stop in NRT in the afternoon but my passport at that time will only hvae 4 months validity remaining.

Will that be ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum passport validity for travelling to Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68535/minimum-passport-validity-for-travelling-to-japan)

Comment: I don't think that's a dupe, as it doesn't address Transit Visas or TWOV.

Answer (score 4):

Airlines are required to return a passenger to their point of departure if the passenger is refused entry at a transit point or a destination, and they must do so at the airline's expense (although the airline may well seek to collect it from the passenger under the airline's terms of carriage). Therefore, airlines are very careful to check whether a passenger has the correct travel documents.

The database at Timatic ([here's an article about Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) on Wikipedia) is the common reference. [Here's a Timatic portal](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html); there are others as well. The airline will check for your admissibility in both Japan (for transit), and for admission into the United States.

Presuming that you're an Indian citizen, entering your information into the Timatic portal above yields this info about transiting in Japan:

***TWOV (Transit Without Visa):***

*Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar
day. They must stay in the international transit area of the
airport and have documents required for the next destination.*

Because your Japan transit will take place within one calendar day, you may TWOV in Japan provided you stay in the international transit area at NRT.

Under the USA section, Timatic displays this:

***Passport required.***

*Passports issued to nationals of India must be valid for the
period of intended stay.*

...

*Visa required.*

Because your passport is valid for the period of your intended stay in the US, the airline should board you for these flights if you have a visa for entry into the United States.